# i2cdetect shows unknown addresses and addresses don't change when new I2C device plugged in. What are these addresses?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, nvidia-jetson

How do I know which I2C is an actual I2C device and what are these addresses?

My system/ my computer is an Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier and I have no I2C devices plugged in to it at the time I am running all these `i2cdetect` commands below. I do have a Gy-521 gyro connected over I2C that I have plugged in and looked for. The problem is when this gyro is plugged in that nothing looks any different with `i2cdetect` from 0 through 8.
I have 0 through 8 options on I2C to look for addresses. I will go through each of them with `i2cdetect` starting with 0.

```
$ i2cdetect -r -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: 50 -- -- -- -- -- 56 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

An address at 50 and 56 it would seem.

```
$ i2cdetect -r -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- 74 -- -- --


$ i2cdetect -r -y 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  

$ i2cdetect -r -y 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          ^Z^X^C
```

When I get to 3 it hangs when it would otherwise print out the addresses.

```
$ i2cdetect -r -y 4
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: 20 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- --
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- --
50: 50 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

$ i2cdetect -r -y 5
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- ^C^X^Z  

$ i2cdetect -r -y 6
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          ^C^X^Z
```

5 and 6 also hang and do not print all the addresses.

```
$ i2cdetect -r -y 7
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

$ i2cdetect -r -y 8
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- 74 -- -- --
```

As I've said. There are no I2C devices plugged in and when there are I2C devices plugged in they don't look any different than this.

Comment: That system apparently uses the i2c devices for some internal communication (e.g system temperature sensors or fan control), that in itself is not really something to worry about. What addresses are you expecting the gyro to see at?

Comment: On bus 1 or bus 8. I never see a change in `i2cdetect -r -y 8` or `i2cdetect -r -y 1` when I plug in or unplug the gyro. I restart the system and I never see any change in the 'detecting'. I wonder if there is some config file I need to change for i2c to work. Though I haven't seen anything like this with the Jetson AGX Xavier.

Comment: Have you tried without the `-r` parameter? The documentation https://linux.die.net/man/8/i2cdetect suggests that it should not be used. I've never used it, either.

Comment: I just get a few lines when I don't use `-r` [terminal here](https://imgur.com/XVVxbKL)

Comment: Hmm... Sorry, can't help you there. You should probably look for documentation from the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks anyway. It's a lonely question.